# Using Promises in NodeJS (Parse Server)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get used to Promises. My Parse Server environment always returns a promise, however I need to mix Parse functions with some of my own functions that I would like to work in accordance with the Parse way of doing things.

Here is my code

```
savePrescription(user, prescription)
   //Returning an object (working!) to be passed to the next function.
        .then(function(savedProgData) {
            console.log(savedProgData) <-- undefined!
            getSavedData(savedProgData)
        })
        .then(function(savedIds) {
            console.log(savedIds); <-- undefined!
            sendClientProgrammes(savedIds)
        })
        .then(function(returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData);
            response.success();
        }, function(err) {
            response.error(err);
        })

    function sendClientProgrammes(savedIds) {
        console.log('running send client programmes');
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return resolve();
        })
    }

    function getSavedData(savedProgData) {
        console.log('running getSavedData');
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var savedIds = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < savedProgData.length; i++) {
                    savedIds.push(savedProgData[i].id)
                }
                if(savedIds.length > 0) {
                    console.log(true);
                    return resolve(savedIds);
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
        })
    }
```

At the end of this I am getting a `{code: 107, message: "The server returned an invalid response."}` error.

How can I 'promisfy' my standard JS functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the results of your functions so the promises are passed down.

```
.then(function(savedProgData) {
    return getSavedData(savedProgData)
})
```

Comment: @Dehli, apologies to bother you for a silly question but I'm a bit curious, Parse.Promise.as() vs Node Promise.resolve() , Node Promises are faster, right?

Comment: Yes, I imagine native Promises are faster and I would recommend using them over `Parse.Promise`. It looks like as of v2 they're no longer around (https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS#upgrading-to-parse-sdk-200). Cheers! @Code_Crash

Comment: @Dehli, Thanks for the response and clearing my doubts! 

You are right about the new version, now we can't use the Parse.Promises(), So I'm converting my oldest version of code to new version, that's why I ask you this question. Thanks again!

Happy Coding!